# MATLAB Searching for a given position within a string of numbers and underscores

Tags: string, matlab, search

In my logs trials are coded like this:

```
12_120_20_120_1
```

The only indicator of the trial type is the second last number between the underscores.
I would like matlab to search for a given number, in a given position.
I tried coding it as 'star_star_star_120_star'
But it does not work.

In fact, looking for strings with '* *' does not work for me at all, when I am using  code like:

```
if length (strfind (logs{nl,4}, '9_220_20_120_2'))>0
```

*(the above code works, it does not feature stars and it will only find one trial, I want it to find all trials in 120 in position star_star_star_120_star)*

I cannot just search for 120 within a string,

```
[if length (strfind (logs{nl,4}, '120'))>0]
```

cause it will also appear in different positions of possible strings in that column, so it will also return what i am NOT looking for
(e.g. '9_120_20_160_2').

*(by 'star' I mean the star symbol, it dissapears when I type it here)*

I am ready to clarify, if this is not unclear.

here are a few lines of my typical log:

> Subject    Trial   Event Type  Code    Time    TTime   Uncertainty Duration    Uncertainty ReqTime ReqDur  Stim Type   Pair Index
>
> MROT_PILOT_09_03_M6    222 Picture INSTRUKACJA_PRT2    37667   0   1   111167  1   0   next    other   0
>   MROT_PILOT_09_03_M6 222 Pulse   111 148743  111076  0
>   MROT_PILOT_09_03_M6 223 Picture PRZERWA 148834  0   1   100167  1   0   next    other   0
>   MROT_PILOT_09_03_M6 223 Pulse   111 173703  24868   0
>   MROT_PILOT_09_03_M6 223 Pulse   111 198743  49909   0
>   MROT_PILOT_09_03_M6 223 Pulse   111 223702  74868   0
>   MROT_PILOT_09_03_M6 223 Pulse   111 248663  99829   0
>   MROT_PILOT_09_03_M6 224 Picture FIX 249002  0   1   10167   1   0   next    other   0
>   MROT_PILOT_09_03_M6 225 Picture 11_60_80_20_2   259168  0   1   50167   1   0   50000   hit 11
>   MROT_PILOT_09_03_M6 225 Pulse   111 273703  14534   0
>   MROT_PILOT_09_03_M6 225 Response    2   292049  32880   1

(Idk how to format this better, sorry)

here is the important part of my code:

```
MRIpulse= find (strcmp (logs (:,3) , 'Pulse'));
firstMRIpulse =MRIpulse(1)

for nl = firstMRIpulse:length (logs (:,1))

 %HARD2   

if length (strfind (logs{nl,4}, '9_220_20_160_2'))>0

    if length (strfind (logs {nl,12}, 'hit'))>0
         HARD2SCORE (end +1) = 1;
    else HARD2SCORE (end +1) = 0;

    for nextrow = nl+1:length (logs (:,1))
        if length (strfind (logs{nextrow,3}, 'Response'))>0
   HARD2RT(end +1) = str2num (logs{nextrow,6})
   break
        end 
    end
    end
end
```

Comment: You could use `regexp` instead of `strfind`, something like this `regexp('12_120_20_120_1','\d+_\d+_\d+_120_\d+')` (where `\d` means a numeric digit and `+` means "one or more"). However it sounds like you're reading log text files, so I would suggest converting those codes to 5 columns of numbers when you read them in. How are you reading in the files? Can you give a example line from the log file?

Comment: @Monica please move all that code in your comment to your question (you can edit your question). It's not fun trying to read it in comments.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: This is definitely a problem for `regexp`. Define clearly the structure of the string you're looking for, whether it's always digits or characters and how many you expect between each underscore. Then you can construct a regular expression which will pick out all matches.

Comment: Thank you for your input. 

Unfortunately I won't always expect the same number of digits between each underscore. 

My structure is always:
'something_something_something_sthimportant_something'
where 'something' is a number composed of 1-3 digits, and 'sthimportant' is the number that I am interested in and want to define in my code.

Comment: It seems that I can't simply replace strfind with regexp in my code. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Blindly copy+pasting code generally doesn't work. We're unfortunately not yet omniscient, *what* did you try and why didn't it work?

Comment: As opposed to doing something elegant and using `regexp`, how about just string search the last and second last underscores and extract the number in between? @Monica: you should include as an example the actual strings you are dealing with. For example, in the log you shared, could you highlight the important part you are trying to extract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to this problem. I modified the code in the following way:

instead of:

```
if length (strfind (logs{nl,4}, '9_220_20_160_2'))>0
```

I have:

```
 if strfind (logs{nl,4},'_')
     ind=strfind(logs{nl,4},'_')

    if strcmp (logs{nl,4} (ind (3)+1:ind(4)-1), '40')>0
```

So basically I create indexes for each underscore in my trial code (which is always formatted like this: 'number_number_number_number_number'), and I look for the number (which is actually formally a string) between the 3th and 4th underscore.

I also changed strfind to strcmp, cause e.g. if my trial name is '9_220_20_160_2', and I used strfind the result would be positive for both '160' and '60', however if I use strcmp it will be positive for '160' only (so it makes my search more precise).

The rest of the code stays the same.

If anyone's interested I can further clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `strsplit`. I find it easier to understand and very easy to change what you search for.

```
spst = strsplit(logs{n1,4}); % Assuming logs{n1,4} is that x_y_z_XXX_w
numBeforeLast = str2double(spst{4}); % Number before the last underscore - XXX you are searching for.
if (numBeforeLast == number_you_are_searching_for)
    % You found the case, do whatever you want with it.
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Well, I think that at this point it seems to just be a question of personal preferences, cause the solution I presented works perfectly fine, and it adds the same number of lines to the code.